# Highcharts export with selected points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to generate line and column graphs. In some cases, I'm programmatically selecting points in the chart. This works fine, until I try to export the graph - selected points are not selected in exported image.

I tried manual selecting points, I added export functionality to it and it doesn't work either. After selecting some points, these are not present in the exported chart. Nothing special in the code, just simple graph with enabled export and allowed manual point selection:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        exporting: {
            buttons: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enabled: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});
```

You can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JTbnU/

**Is export with selected points supported by Highcharts?**

Comment: You example is working fine. Maybe there was a bug in previous version.

Comment: As I wrote in the e-mail earlier, you were right, works in 3.0. We have some troubles with migrating to new version, but that's different story :)